# Signals and slots implementation in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, delegates, multicastdelegate

Does an implementation of the signals and slots mechanism for event dispatching exist for Delphi?

Comment: Non-multicast event handling is built in. It's just the multicast part that needs add-ons.

Comment: I added a mixup of the suggested methods at https://bitbucket.org/MX4399/multicast-events-using-generics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for multicast events. There are a few implementations out there, e.g.

- http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=137
- http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/09/03/38867
- http://www.codebot.org/delphi/?doc=9568

Some of them need generics, so are D>2009 only.

Comment: TApplicationEvents uses eventsink too.

Comment: @Downvoter: I tried to use TApplicationEvents for my own multicast events once. Unfortunately it's designed mostly un-reuseable, like most of the VCL. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can implement multi-cast events yourself, they are not directly supported in the the language unlike in C# and VB.NET.  Lack of language support makes any attempt to emulate multi-cast events rather clumsy.

Interestingly, C++ lacks support for signals and slots and the Qt solution involves an extra process in the compilation tool chain, the Meta Object Compiler.

Comment: More importantly, the *VCL* and the *IDE* don't support whatever *your* implementation of multi-cast events is, making it's use clumsy. The language as-is could be used to implement nice multi-cast events, even implement the full-blown registration-free "signals and slots" thing (using RTTI Attributes). Using operator overloading you can almost get C# syntax working.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time a while ago getting Allen Bauer's Multicast Event code working. It has some limitations, but works well in my code. You can see the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225256/getting-allen-bauers-tmulticasteventt-working).

Of course, it only works in Delphi > 2009

Comment: The original post from Allen only supported 32 bit. If you are looking for a version that supports 64 bit as well you can find it here: https://github.com/JensBorrisholt/OnlineOffline