# Is there an equivalent in Delphi for the Java listeners principle?

Tags: java, delphi, events

I'm just curious on this one. I know two ways of defining events in Delphi, using the callback principle, and the windows messages principle.

However, the messages principle is not object-oriented, and the callbacks are only suited for one instance.

I would like a nice solution for having one event, where two different objects can perform an action after the event fires.

In Java, I could simply add another listener.

Does anyone know any equivalent approach in Delphi to this nice listener's principle?

Comment: Delphi FMX (think VCL too) seems to have (probably mostly for internal use) such "events" to allow monitoring the lifetime of components. Probably useful for design containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are also known as multi-cast events and Allen Bauer wrote a nice article titled [Multicast events using generics](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/08/15/38865) giving good coverage of the topic.

In short, multi-cast events are not baked into the language/framework like in Java C#, but can be simulated with some extra work. The introduction of generics has made this somewhat simpler.

Comment: Thanks, multi-cast events is the term for it in Delphi. Too bad it isn't incorporated in the language/IDE.

Comment: Have a look at the `TApplicationEvents` component.  It uses multicast events, without using Generics.

Answer (score 1):

There is already [a similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788267/signals-and-slots-implementation-in-delphi) on SO with some additional links to existing multicast implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a design pattern called observer or listener ([http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObserverPattern](http://Observe%20Pattern%20by%20Ward%20Cunningham)). I guess that you could write the implementation of your object in such a way that you could register a list of observers that could be notified of any change in your code.

Comment: Of course, but it would be nice to use a standard solution supported by the native language.