# Default Generic Comparer for methods returns incorrect results

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe

In using a proposed [multicast delegate](http://www.codebot.org/delphi/?doc=9568) approach in response to the [Signals and slots implementation in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788267/signals-and-slots-implementation-in-delphi) question, the code fails to add more than one event handler.

The problem is related to adding methods to the event list in `TDelegateImpl<T>.Add()`, the `TList<T>.IndexOf` method uses a Compare method to find existing methods and the result is always 0 - meaning Left and Right is the same for a TMethod. The Equals method uses a `TMethod` type cast and explicitly compares `TMethod.Code` and `TMethod.Data`, where `Compare` casts to an address which is always the same.

Why is `Compare` used in `TList<T>.IndexOf` and not `Equals`?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no default comparer for TMethod types, so who wrote the comparer that is being used?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Its the standard Delphi XE lib (see Generics.Defaults.pas - lines 1070 to 1094)

Comment: Yes, I see there is a comparer for TMethods. But it uses PInt64(Left)^ etc. to access the method. That works in Win32, but not in Win64, where one pointer is already 64 bits, so a TMethod is 128 bits.

Comment: @Rudy Will you stop going on about 64 bit. XE is 32 bit. That comparer doesn't even work in 32 bit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this function:

```
function Compare_Method(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right: TMethodPointer): Integer;
begin
  if PInt64(@Left)^ < PInt64(@Right)^ then
    Result := -1
  else if PInt64(@Left)^ > PInt64(@Right)^ then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

This compares methods as Int64s. That doesn't work, since @ probably has no effect here.

The CPU view confirms this:

```
System.Generics.Defaults.pas.1089: begin
00447690 55               push ebp
00447691 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
System.Generics.Defaults.pas.1090: if PInt64(@Left)^ < PInt64(@Right)^ then
00447693 8B4510           mov eax,[ebp+$10]
00447696 8B5004           mov edx,[eax+$04]
00447699 8B00             mov eax,[eax]
0044769B 8B4D08           mov ecx,[ebp+$08]
0044769E 3B5104           cmp edx,[ecx+$04]
004476A1 7506             jnz $004476a9
004476A3 3B01             cmp eax,[ecx]
004476A5 7309             jnb $004476b0
004476A7 EB02             jmp $004476ab
004476A9 7D05             jnl $004476b0
System.Generics.Defaults.pas.1091: Result := -1
004476AB 83C8FF           or eax,-$01
004476AE EB21             jmp $004476d1
System.Generics.Defaults.pas.1092: else if PInt64(@Left)^ > PInt64(@Right)^ then
004476B0 8B4510           mov eax,[ebp+$10]
etc...
```

To compare two TMethods as Int64s, this should be:

```
System.Generics.Defaults.pas.1090: if PInt64(@Left)^ < PInt64(@Right)^ then
00447693 8B4510           lea eax,[ebp+$10] // not MOV
00447696 8B5004           mov edx,[eax+$04]
00447699 8B00             mov eax,[eax]
0044769B 8B4D08           lea ecx,[ebp+$08] // not MOV
0044769E 3B5104           cmp edx,[ecx+$04]
004476A1 7506             jnz $004476a9
004476A3 3B01             cmp eax,[ecx]
etc...
```

This clearly shows that `PInt64(@Left)^` is interpreted as `PInt64(Left)^`.

A proper implementation should more or less look like this, for both Delphi 32 and Delphi 64:

```
function Compare_Method(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right: TMethodPointer): Integer;
var
  LCode, LData: PByte;
  RCode, RData: PByte;
begin
  LCode := PByte(TMethod(Left).Code);
  LData := PByte(TMethod(Left).Data);
  RCode := PByte(TMethod(Right).Code);
  RData := PByte(TMethod(Right).Data);
  if LData < RData then
    Result := -1
  else if LData > RData then
    Result := 1
  else if LCode < RCode then
    Result := -1
  else if LCode > RCode then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: It doesn't even work in 32 bit Windows so this explains nothing. The question pertains to XE which is 32 bit only. The XE2 code will, I'm sure, be different for 64 bit targets.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the XE tag. My solution should work for all platforms, though.

Comment: @MX4399 Windows version is not pertinent, we are talking about Delphi versions. You are using 32 bit Delphi.

Comment: @David: no, it is not different for 64 bit targets, AFAICT.

Comment: @Rudy Sorry, I didn't understand that comment.

Comment: Right, I fixed the code (it was essentially correct) and turned the downcote into an upvote. With that comparer I can now get the desired output. I've no idea what the real `Compare_Method` actually does!

Comment: @Rudy Does your comment mean that XE2's `Compare_Method` still have the int64 cast code even for 64 bit? That's pretty lame, although since it doesn't work in 32 bits either I think the 32/64 bit issue is the least of anyone's worries!!

Comment: @David: that code was actually copied from XE2's implementation. I didn't see an $IFDEF there, so it is the code for D32 and D64.

Comment: @Rudy That confirms what Ville said. I'm not impressed. Do you want to do the QC report, or should I?

Comment: @David: Please do. I'm in my clinic and not entirely free. I don't have QC installed here either.

Comment: @David, Rudy: Good work finding the cause. I've voted on the QC. Lets hope Embarcadero add unit tests for these collections after this.

Comment: @Ville: Indeed. I am a bit amazed they didn't. They tend to test everything that can be tested.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce this and it is very clearly a bug in the default comparer for methods.

I have filed [QC#98942](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98942).

Here's my code:

```
program TMethodComparer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyMethod = procedure of object;

type
  TMyClass = class
  published
    procedure P1;
    procedure P2;
    procedure P3;
  end;

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.P1;
begin
end;

procedure TMyClass.P2;
begin
end;

procedure TMyClass.P3;
begin
end;

var
  List: TList<TMyMethod>;
  MyObject1, MyObject2: TMyClass;

begin
  MyObject1 := TMyClass.Create;
  MyObject2 := TMyClass.Create;
  List := TList<TMyMethod>.Create;
  List.Add(MyObject1.P1);
  List.Add(MyObject1.P2);
  List.Add(MyObject2.P1);
  List.Add(MyObject2.P2);
  Writeln(List.IndexOf(MyObject1.P1));
  Writeln(List.IndexOf(MyObject1.P2));
  Writeln(List.IndexOf(MyObject2.P1));
  Writeln(List.IndexOf(MyObject2.P2));
  Writeln(List.IndexOf(MyObject1.P3));
end.
```

**Output**

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

**Expected output**

```
0
1
2
3
-1
```

The default comparer in `Generics.Defaults` is implemented like this:

```
type
  TMethodPointer = procedure of object;

function Compare_Method(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right: TMethodPointer): Integer;
begin
  if PInt64(@Left)^ < PInt64(@Right)^ then
    Result := -1
  else if PInt64(@Left)^ > PInt64(@Right)^ then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

I can understand what this is attempting to do, but it fails miserably. I still can't work out how these casts pan out.

I believe that the 32 bit version of `Compare_Method` should have been written this way:

```
function Compare_Method(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right: TMethod): Integer;
begin
  if Int64(Left) < Int64(Right) then
    Result := -1
  else if Int64(Left) > Int64(Right) then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

And this does lead to the expected output.

Clearly for a 64 bit target (i.e. in XE2) no approach based on aliasing with a 64 bit integer will work.

So, in order to workaround the bug, you can add the following functions:

```
function Compare_Method(const Left, Right: TMethod): Integer;
var
  LCode, LData: PByte;
  RCode, RData: PByte;
begin
  LCode := PByte(Left.Code);
  LData := PByte(Left.Data);
  RCode := PByte(Right.Code);
  RData := PByte(Right.Data);
  if LData<RData then
    Result := -1
  else if LData>RData then
    Result := 1
  else if LCode<RCode then
    Result := -1
  else if LCode>RCode then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function CompareMyMethod(const Left, Right: TMyMethod): Integer;
begin
  Result := Compare_Method(TMethod(Left), TMethod(Right))
end;
```

And then create the list like this:

```
List := TList<TMyMethod>.Create(
  TComparer<TMyMethod>.Construct(CompareMyMethod)
);
```

Comment: Why do they compare methods as `PInt64(@Left)^` and `PInt64(@Right)^`? Sorting? It must surely be for identity purposes only as its used by IndexOf? @Rudy Velthuis - any ideas?

Comment: But why use `Compare` in `IndexOf()`, should `Equals` not be used? I don't understand. (besides the possible bug)

Comment: @MX4399 `IComparer<T>` only has one method, `Compare`.

Comment: Could it be alignment issue? Ie if the TMethod isn't packed record (I havn't checked) then it might actually be bigger than 64 bits...?

Comment: The expected output should be "0,1,0,1,-1" and I get this with XE2 in 32-bit compilation. In 64-bit compilation I get only zeros so the bug is still there for 64-bit in XE2 but not in 32-bit.

Comment: @ville No, expected output is as I said. Look more closely and you will see two instances.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Then the bug is still there in XE2 for both 32-bit and 64-bit however it behaves slightly differently :)

Comment: @Ville I'm astounded that Generics.Defaults code have passed code review for XE2 release. That's a blindingly obvious unit to check with a fine toothcomb. It does all sorts of crazy low-level casting, bit twiddling. Unit tests clearly aren't up to much at Emba. Not impressed.

Comment: @MX4399: A generic list uses IComparer<T> for all kinds of things. It does not have an IEqualityComparer<T> reference, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rudy: Which generic container class would then EXPLICITLY map to `Equals` (via `IEqualityComparer`) in this case for `IndexOf()` calls? The approach in `TList<T>` seems to be a cheat/quicky - sorry - I have a bee in my bonnet about why `Equals` is not used for 'IndexOf()' if there is such a funky generic framework in place here.

Comment: `TDictionary<K,V>` uses `IEqualityComparer<>`. You don't want a dictionary though. You can fix this easily enough by creating your list with your own comparer that works. `TList<>` is quite right to use `IComparer<>` since it offers a `Sort` method.

Comment: @David: I created a `TCustomComparer<T>` and passed it to `TList<T>.Create()` and needed to type cast in `Compare()` like `_left := TMethod((@Left)^)` and same for right to compare both code and  data.

Comment: @MX4399 That's the wrong solution. Just call `TComparer<T>.Construct()` and pass in a `TComparison<T>`. That's by far the easiest way. And You don't need the `@` I believe. Just write it as `TMethod(Left)`.

Comment: @MX4399 See the bottom of my latest edit. I show there how to workaround the bug.

Comment: @David: I am having trouble with that suggested workaround and kept the TCustomComparer + there is a spurious releasing interface bug in the test code - see : https://bitbucket.org/MX4399/multicast-events-using-generics. Tx