# How to listen for events without create the object

Tags: delphi, oop, events, delphi-xe

I'm facing a problem that I can't find a way in Delphi to solve it.

I have a pop up menu and I have an event for when the person select this option, what I want to do is broadcast this event for any object that registry to it.

The problem that I'm facing is that I can just registry to the event if I have an instance of the pop up menu created, but if I do create an instance just to listen do this event still it is a different instance and I wont be able to listen to it.

How can I archive this goal of have many objects listen to an event of one object in Delphi?

Thanks

Comment: Is this event the selection of a menu item or the popup of the menu?

Comment: Can you post some code that shows the instance is a different one?

Comment: I will create some sample code and post here, but there are some more explanation in the replay to Remy bellow. Thanks guys.

Comment: Just a guess: Are you looking for this http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2009/09/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2/ in Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi does not natively support multicasting of events. You have to create your own mechanism for that. The simplest solution is to store your registered objects/handlers in a list, then loop through that list when the event is triggered, calling each object/handler as needed.  For example:

[Simulating multicast events in Win32 Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa051005a.htm)

Allen Bauer wrote a series of blog articles about a more advanced way to implement multicasting events in Delphi:

[Multicast events using generics](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/08/15/38865)
[Multicast Events - the cleanup](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/08/25/38866)
[Multicast Events - the finale](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/09/03/38867)

[Getting Allen Bauer's TMulticastEvent<T> working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225256/getting-allen-bauers-tmulticasteventt-working)

Comment: That my sound damn, but I how can I do that from few different units. So for example I have the PopUp unit that is created by the main and sends the boadcast to the main form, then I have a object inside another inside another object, lets say rightPanel and inside comandGridPanel and inside Grid. If I want to make my event go all the way to the grid I need to have my rightPanel registry to the event, then it would create a new event to comandGridPanel  and finally comandGridPanel would create a new event to grid? I think your solution is more horizontal and my problem is more vertical.

Comment: Thanks Remy excellent response. I was researching for broadcast (the name we use in Object-C) not multicast so I wasn't getting much other then internet stuff. Thanks.